# How to update an entire object in a list C#?

Tags: c#

I have a list of object and I want to replace one of the objects in the list with the new object:

```
public Parent AppendParentChildren(Request request)
    {
        var Children = request.Parent.Children.ToList();
        if (Children.Any(x => x.TrackingNumber == request.Child.TrackingNumber))
        {
            //Here I want to replace any Children that have the same tracking number in the list with the new Child passed in
        }
        else
        {
            Children.Add(request.Child);
        }
        request.Parent.Children = Children;
        return request.Parent;
    }

public class Request
{
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }

}

public class Parent 
{
    public IEnumerable<Child> Children {get;set;}
}
```

If I try and use it in a loop:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static void Update<T>(this List<T> items, T newItem)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
        //this
            item = newItem;
        }
    }
}
```

item is read only, so I cannot replace the object in the list.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you ever heard of   _loops_?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, sorry. Can you edit your post and clarify please?

Comment: Are you sure you want to replace multiple objects with the same tracking number with the same object?  You will have the object duplicated in your list at that point.

Comment: [C# Basics Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/)

Comment: I have updated for clarity

Comment: @TimSchmelter If you try and replace the object in a loop, the current object in the loop is readonly

Comment: @SteveMitcham most of the time it will be a single item, but on the offchance that there are two it would be fine for the object to be duplicated.

Comment: Since you expose Children as `IEnumerable<T>` you are indicating a read only semantic.  If you intend to change the value, then change it to `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the member of a foreach iteration because foreach implements the `IEnumerable` type which is read-only. 
A solution would be to cast the list of items inside the extension method as a `List` (which is read-writable). Then you'd want to identify which item(s) in the list you are replacing and update them. Below is what the Update extension method would look like (assuming you're in a situation where you can use LINQ)

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static void Update<T>(this List<T> items, T newItem)
    {   
        var childList = items as List<Child>;
        var newChildItem = newItem as Child;
        var matches = childList.Where(x => x.TrackingNumber == newChildItem.TrackingNumber).ToList();
        matches.ForEach(x => childList[childList.IndexOf(x)] = newChildItem);
    }
}
```

I've put a working example (albeit slightly bloated) on dotnetfiddle
https://dotnetfiddle.net/MJ5svP

It's also worth noting that although it looks like you're altering childList, this is actually referenced back to the original list not creating a copy (more info on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064534/does-casting-create-new-object))