# Casting and Disposing - IDataReader

Tags: c#, vb.net, idisposable

Let's say I created a data reader.

I have a method in my database class - that creates it that way:

```
db.ExecuteReaderIDb(sSQL)
```

I can assign this right away to a using statement, and it will get disposed of at the end, but I wanted to use the HasRows property, meaning I want to cast to System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.

My question involves performing an immediate cast to System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.

In this case, if I cast in the using statement, a couple questions:
1.  Does it create 2 objects?
2.  If applicable, will both objects get disposed of if I call Dispose of what I casted to?

Otherwise, do I need 2 using statements, the one that returns IDataReader, and the one that performs the cast to ensure everything is properly cleaned up.

Comment: You have a method `ExecuteReaderIDb` which returns _what_? Why you don't show more of your code including the `using`? Maybe then it would be clearer

Comment: Where do you usually see two objects being created due to casting?

Comment: it returns an IDataReader

Comment: No new object is created by the cast.  Do consider changing the return type of that function to DbDataReader, IDataReader is not very useful.

Comment: The term "cast" is used in programming pretty much as it is elsewhere.  Have you ever heard the expression "to cast something in a different light"?  It basically means to look at something in a different way.  That's how casting in programming works.  You are still dealing with the same object but you're accessing it via a reference of a different type.  You can easily test that for yourself by using something like `If myThing Is DirectCast(myThing, SomeType) Then`. If that condition is `True` then obviously no new object has been created. No need to ask about what you can test.

Comment: @HansPassant ...ill consider that...the inner workings are the oracle managed DLL...but i didnt want to expose that class directly...trying to clean up a lot of programs that have some direct references

Comment: Hmm, no, DbDataReader is abstract.  You are going to cast, so it has to be one anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting doesn't create a new object.

```
Using reader = db.ExecuteReaderIDb(sSQL)
  Dim someOtherReader = CType(reader, System.Data.Common.DbDataReader)

  ' someOtherReader and reader point to the same object
  ' disposing reader will also dispose someOtherReader
End Using
```

You could always cast right in the using

```
Using reader = CType(db.ExecuteReaderIDb(sSQL), System.Data.Common.DbDataReader)
    ...
End Using
```

Comment: thanks...i found some more info here...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064534/does-casting-create-new-object ...i just wanted to make sure it pertained to IDisposable which is quite a special thing in .NET...thanks